# Oracle BI Publisher - Dynamic number of columns

Tags: oracle11g, dynamic-columns, bi-publisher

I'm creating a report in BI Publisher using the BI Publisher Desktop tool for Word.

What I need is to have a table with a dynamic column number.

Let's imagine I'm listing stocks by store: Each line is an item and I need to have a column for each store in the database, but that must be dynamic because a store can be created or deleted at any moment.

The number of stores, i.e., the number of columns that need to exist is obtained from an SQL query that goes into the report by a data set.

The query will be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS STORE_COUNT FROM STORE;` in a data set named G_1, so the number of columns is the variable `G_1::STORE_COUNT`.

Is there any way that can be achieved?

I'm developing the report using an .rtf file, so any help related would be appretiated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.rtf` file with the column names mapped to a `.xdo` or `.xdm` file. The mapped column in `.xdo` or `.xdm` file should be in the cursor or the select statement of your stored procedure of function.